# Como resolver Fatal error: Call to undefined function ContaUsuario() in

Tags: php, pdo

No meu caso eu tenho essa função :

no arquivo Home bem no inicio importei aqui:

```
    <?php

      require_once("session.php");

      require_once("class_usuario.php");
      $auth_user = new USER();


      $user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

      $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM N00_Usuario WHERE idUsuario=:user_id");
      $stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));

      $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    ?>

    e no arquivo Home importei a classe que está dentro do arquivo Class_usuario:
    <?php

      require_once("session.php");

      require_once("class_usuario.php");
      $auth_user = new USER();


      $user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

      $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM N00_Usuario WHERE idUsuario=:user_id");
      $stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));

      $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    ?>

<div class="box bg-primary">
                  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                  <?php 

                  try{
                    $a= ContaUsuario($connection) ;
                  }

                catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
                  ?>
                  <h3><?php echo $a;?></h3>
                  <p class="lead">Page views</p>
                </div>
              </div>
```

o que tem de errado?Alguém tem uma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize sua classe e chame o método.

```
try{
      $result =  $auth_user->ContaUsuario($connection);
      <h3><?php echo $result;?></h3>
 }
```

Comment: eu vou tentar para ver o que dá @Felipe

Comment: Caso não funcione publique aqui, que tento achar outra forma. @Gladiador

Comment: Então @Felipe o erro contiua. Talvez pq expliquei errado. a função está em um outro arquivo chamado Class_Usuario e a parte <h3><?php echo $a;?></h3> também está em um outro arquivo Home. Estou querendo lista o numero total de usuario cadastrado

Comment: Você importou o arquivo Class_Usuario? Tem como postar o codigo de Class_Usuario? @Gladiador
Se for uma classe php você deve instanciar um objeto da classe e chamar o metodo.

`$obj = new Class_Usuario();
$rows = $obj.ContaUsuario($connection);  `

Comment: acabei de postar o código . editei para você ver e se consegue ver algo de errado.

Comment: O que você postou é só o código do arquivo Home? @Gladiador

Comment: postei os dois camarada. em cima é da class_usuario e no final e do Home

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68780/discussion-between-felipe-and-gladiador).

Comment: @Gladiador marque como respondida , isso ajuda a comunidade e outras pessoas que forem ver a questão.